# On the maximum number of common integer solutions in a system of polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

If we have $n$ degree $d$ algebraically independent polynomials in $n$ variables in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ then

1. what is the maximum number of common integer solutions the system can have?
2. same as 1. but if only $n-k$ of them are algebraically independent?

Comment: I take it that by "solutions" you mean *common zeroes*.

Comment: 'common integer zeros'.

Comment: If there are algebraic dependencies, then there could be infinitely many common integer zeros.

Comment: If the polynomials are independent, then there can be at least $d^n$ common zeroes, from the case $p_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(x_i-1)\cdots(x_i-d)$.

Comment: @MattF. Will $x_1x_2=m!$ work as an even more extreme case?

Comment: $x_1x_2x_3=m!$ and $x_1x_2+(x_3-1)^2=m!$ and $x_1x_2+(x_3-1)^3=m!$ works? $n=3$ and $d=3$?

Comment: Those three polynomials are not algebraically independent. And the first two polynomials by themselves probably have no common integer zeroes if $m>3$.

Comment: Why do you say the second statement? $x_1=20$ and $x_2=6$ and $x_3=1$?